# Link clicked, outlines button until clicked elsewhere

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've always wondered how one could resolve the following scenario:

You have a navigation menu on a one-page website. When a navigation link is clicked it scrolls to that section of the website. However, the clicked navigation link has the outline of being clicked.

Is it possible to clear this outline after being clicked? Reset the look so it looks like it was never clicked at all. Without having to click on another element?

Comment: Yes, that's entirely possible with CSS. Assuming you just want to change the link colour, Just set the colour of `a` tags. If you want to target specifically for visited links, you can also use `a:visited`, but you should set the colour for both visited and unvisited links at the same time. If you're talking about a while DIV that changes colour, you'd need to post your HTML for us to work out exactly which element to target.

Comment: Thank you so much, so useful and helpful. I am truly appreciative!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This CSS property you are referring to as the "dotted line" is the `outline` property of a "focus"ed DOM element.

You can read up about best practices for handling the outline of an element here: http://www.outlinenone.com/

As outlined on that site, if you must remove it, you can quickly do so by adding the following CSS declaration, however for accessibility it is recommended that you then create a replacement focus style if implementing the below:

`:focus {
     outline: 0;
}`